# Проблема применения матрицы гомографии

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, методы

У меня проблема, мне нужно реализовать отображение пути, пройденного человеком на видео с высоты птичьего полета, используя матрицу гомографии, в качестве точки отсчета взять нижнюю среднюю точку ограничивающей рамки. [Ссылка на набор данных][1].

В описании набора данных говорится:

> Все видео хранятся в папке video, а соответствующие файлы гомографии наземной плоскости хранятся в папке homography.

Кроме того, также предоставляется информация о файле .mat (MATLAB), содержащая гомографию.
**camera_placement.pdf** показывает сетевое местоположение. При сборе набора данных все видео полностью синхронизируются с использованием глобальных временных меток.

Вот фрагмент кода для проецирования местоположения плоскости изображения на плоскость Земли:

`gp Temp = Homography * image position; // image position = [ x y 1 ]'` 
`gp position = [gp Temp(1)/temp(3); gp Temp(2)/temp(3)]';`

Однако я не понимаю, как написать это на python и OpenCV, если я использую функцию `cv2.warpPerspective` и передаю ей матрицу гомографии и размеры изображения, то получается неправильный вид. Кроме того, возникла проблема deque, а именно, как сделать так, чтобы куча была реализована для каждого найденного человека отдельно.

Я много пытался все сделать сам, но так и не смог добиться должного результата.
Вот мой код:

````
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import time
import imutils
from collections import deque
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("/content/YOLOv3-TensorFlow-2.x/yolov3.cfg",
                                 "/content/YOLOv3-TensorFlow-2.x/model_data/yolov3.weights")


net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)


labels = open("/content/YOLOv3-TensorFlow-2.x/coco.names").read().strip().split("\n")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/drive/MyDrive/HallWayTracking/HallWayTracking/videos/001.avi')



layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]


N = 200
pts = deque(maxlen=N)
counter = 0
(dX, dY) = (0, 0)
direction = ""
print(pts)

homography_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/HallWayTracking/HallWayTracking/homography/001.txt"
H = np.loadtxt(homography_path, delimiter=",")
H = H.astype(np.float32) 
homography_matrix = H.reshape((3, 3))  
print(homography_matrix)


colors = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(labels), 3), dtype="uint8")
count = 0

while count < 20:
    count += 1
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blurred, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        height, width = frame.shape[:2]
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
        net.setInput(blob)
        start = time.perf_counter()
        outs = net.forward(output_layers)
        time_took = time.perf_counter() - start
        print("Time took:", time_took)
        confidences, boxes, class_ids = [], [], []


        for output in outs:
            for detection in output:
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                if class_id != 0:
                    continue
                confidence = scores[class_id]
                if confidence > 0.3:
                    center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                    center_y = int(detection[1] * height)

                    w = int(detection[2] * width)
                    h = int(detection[3] * height)
                    x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                    y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                    boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                    confidences.append(float(confidence))
                    class_ids.append(class_id)

        indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)

        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            if i in indexes:
                x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
                pts.appendleft([x + w // 2, y + h])

        font_scale = 1
        thickness = 1
        if len(indexes) > 0:
            for i in indexes.flatten():
                x, y = boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1]
                w, h = boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]
                color = [int(c) for c in colors[class_ids[i]]]
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color=color, thickness=thickness)
                text = f"{labels[class_ids[i]]}: {confidences[i]:.2f}"
                (text_width, text_height) = \
                    cv2.getTextSize(text, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontScale=font_scale, thickness=thickness)[0]
                text_offset_x = x
                text_offset_y = y - 5
                box_coords = (
                    (text_offset_x, text_offset_y), (text_offset_x + text_width + 2, text_offset_y - text_height))
                overlay = frame.copy()
                cv2.rectangle(overlay, box_coords[0], box_coords[1], color=color, thickness=cv2.FILLED)
                frame = cv2.addWeighted(overlay, 0.6, frame, 0.4, 0)
                cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                            fontScale=font_scale, color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=thickness)
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
                cv2.circle(frame, (x + w // 2, y + h), 2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            for i in np.arange(1, len(pts)):
                if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
                    continue
                if counter >= 10 and i == 1 and pts[-10] is not None:
                    dX = pts[-10][0] - pts[i][0]
                    dY = pts[-10][1] - pts[i][1]
                    (dirX, dirY) = ("", "")
                    if np.abs(dX) > 3:
                        dirX = "East" if np.sign(dX) == 1 else "West"
                    if np.abs(dY) > 3:
                        dirY = "North" if np.sign(dY) == 1 else "South"
                    if dirX != "" and dirY != "":
                        direction = "{}-{}".format(dirY, dirX)
                    else:
                        direction = dirX if dirX != "" else dirY
                thickness = int(2) #np.sqrt(N / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
                cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)
            cv2.putText(frame, direction, (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.65, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            cv2.putText(frame, "dx: {}, dy: {}".format(dX, dY),
                        (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)
        
        mapped_im = cv2.warpPerspective(frame, homography_matrix , (width,height))
          
    cv2_imshow(frame)
    counter += 1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cap.release()        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```


  [1]: http://www.santhoshsunderrajan.com/datasets.html#hfh_tracking
````

Comment: по глобальности это уже не вопрос, а предложение написать программу по краткому техзаданию.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin тут проблема не столько краткого техзадания, сколько в том, что есть несколько запросов: неправильный вид и deque. Как говорится на английском SO: "Question must be more focused". Ну и под каждую проблему хорошо бы сократить код до [минимального воспроизводимого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: добрый день не это не техническое задание, просто может, кто-то подсказал бы, как правильно использовать матрицу гомографии, когда я использую cv2.warpPerspective, отображение вида бывает очень искажено